# Read and parse data frame of different lengths in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program that reads frames from a tcp socket on Linux and I am struggling in reading the data properly, because the frame length varies.
The frame looks somehow like this:

```
|start   | length  | Data (contains "hello")      |
|0x81    | 0x05    | 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f     |
|1 byte  | 1byte   | 5 bytes                      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The challenge for me is to figure out when the complete frame was readed into the buffer and to recognize if already the beginning of the next frame was partially readed into the buffer. In this case I need to

1. Process the completely readed frame
2. I need to remove that processed frame from the buffer
3. continue reading the socket until the last frame was readed completely for processing

Thats the code I have so far:

```
int processdata(char **frame, int64_t *readedLength, int64_t clientsock) {
      char *pframe = *frame;
      if (( *readedLength) < 2) {
        //we need at least 2 bytes to be able to determine the frame length
        return 0;
      }

      int64_t len = pframe[1]; // the second byte of the frame contains the length
      if (len <= ( *readedLength)) {
        //we have readed the complete frame -> print to console
        //...
      }

    //if we have readed more than the length of the frame, we started reading already the next frame.
      //check how many bytes we readed from the next frame
      int64_t lengthRemainingBuffer = ( *readedLength) - (len-2);
      if (lengthRemainingBuffer == 0) {
        //no next frame available. Lets still create new empty buffer for next socket read. 
        char *nextFrame = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); 
        *frame = nextFrame;
      } else {
        //we started reading the next frame. Lets create a new buffer with it   
        char *nextFrame = malloc(sizeof(char) * lengthRemainingBuffer); 
        *frame = nextFrame;
      }
      //update the buffer counter
      ( *readedLength) = lengthRemainingBuffer;
      return 0;
    }

    int main() {
      char *incoming = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); //initialize read buffer pointer
      int64_t incoming_length = 0;              //initialize variable to store readed bytes
      /* Setup epoll structures....*/
      //...
      /* The event loop */
      while (1) {
        int64_t count;
        char buf[2]; //reading only 2 bytes

        count = read(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf);
        if (count > 0) {
          //we have data, add it to buffer
          incoming = realloc(incoming, sizeof(char) * (incoming_length + count));
          memcpy(incoming + incoming_length, buf, count);
          incoming_length = incoming_length + count;
        }
        //...
        //lets process the data -> check if we have readed complete frame. If yes: print to console, if not continue reading until we have complete frame
        processdata( & incoming, & incoming_length, events[i].data.fd);
      }
      //...
    }
```

Is this good practice? Am I doing something wrong?
I am grateful for any hints.

---

**Barmar**: "we need at least 4 bytes" -- why? 2 bytes should be enough
**-->** Yes you are right. I fixed it.

**chux**: if (len <= readedLength) { should have caused a compiler warning.
**-->** correct. This was just a typo while I was shrinking the code to the relevant parts.

**jaco0646**: This question belongs to codereview
**-->** This is just a small part of a code which is causing segmentation faults under high load. So its not working. I believe that the problem relies on the shrinked code I posted here.

**Barmer**: Why don't you check the length when reading from the socket, instead of when processing the buffer? If it says length = 5, just read the next 5 bytes. **-->** The dataframe can become very, very big. So I cannot guarantee that after reading the length that I am able to read the complete frame at once. Sometimes the socket is not providing the complete frame at once. So I need to check everytime how much I did read already and how much is still missing. And this is what I am doing the the processdata function.

Comment: Why don't you check the length when reading from the socket, instead of when processing the buffer? If it says `length = 5`, just read the next 5 bytes.

Comment: "we need at least 4 bytes" -- why? 2 bytes should be enough, the start and length.

Comment: `if (len <= readedLength) {` should have caused a compiler warning.  Enable all warnings and re-compile.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jaco0646 codereview is for working code.  `if (len <= readedLength) {` is certainly in error.

Comment: What is the maximum length?  `255, 127, UCHAR_MAX`?

Comment: *The dataframe can become very, very big. So I cannot guarantee that after reading the length that I am able to read the complete frame at once.*  So?  You know how much you have to read, so simply loop until you get that amount of data. *So I need to check everytime how much I did read already and how much is still missing.* No, that's way too complex.  Once you know you need to read 32,124 bytes, **just read 32,124 bytes** and use as many `read()` calls as it takes. You'd do well to just throw away what you've written and start over.

Comment: @Andrew Henle O.P is actually correct about needing to check how much was already received from the packet and how much still needs to be read. In addition, also needs to check that the next byte after packet end is indeed the sync byte (0x81) and if not, probably discard the packet and start looking for the next sync byte.